# Itext5 program get troubles with charset when executed on Windows?

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding, window, itext

I'm developing an application which modifies some PDF on java. The application is finished and it work on my computer (using Linux) but now, I'm trying to execute it on a friend's computer (which use Windows) and it does not work properly. It seems to be a problem with char-set because some characters like é á ó ú doesn't appear, but I don't know how to fix it because I can't find if is a windows-configuration problem or it is a problem of my program in java...

My code is something like:

```
     Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("template.pdf");

      PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("resultados"+direccionamiento+"result"+paciente+".pdf"));

       AcroFields wrt = stamper.getAcroFields();

 if(larga == true){
        File file2 = new File("informes"+direccionamiento+rs+"-"+value+".txt") ; 
        if(file2.exists()){

            try (FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2)) {
                String ll = "" ; 

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));    

            ll = br.readLine() ; 

         wrt.setField("#KEY_"+keylarga, ll) ;

            }
```

(is more than this but I think you can sow the itext's parts)

I think maybe it could be the default charset of the windows computer but I've tried to set it as UTF_8 and it seems to be set in this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the charset in `InputStreamReader` otherwise it will use a default charset whatever that may be.